# Win 10, WAMP, Magento 2.x install using either method help

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

Is there a detail and current guide for a newbie to **install Magento 2 in my test environment**?

I am good at following detail instructions. I have spent over 3 days downloading and reading html and you tube video to answer above question. My environment is laptop with Windows 10, WAMP install and  Composer install. I know they are installs for I get the green light in Wamp. With composer, I use the help and list command as directed to confirm it runs.

**Method 1: Using composer**

I read
"composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition ".

**I am using standard Wamp directory settings (ie C:wamp).**

What do I exactly use/type in the "composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento ..." command and where do I execute this command. In a tutorial, there was a mention of clicking and seeing the composer selection. When I install composer, I was not given a shell extension. New to composer and magento.

**Method 2:** I tried by downloaded

1) `Magento-CE-2.0.9-2016-08-10-03-31-28.tar.bz2`

2) `Magento-CE-2.1.1_sample_data-2016-08-29-06-53-55.tar.bz2. Unzip and place into c:wamp/www.`

Looking at 1) in localhost, I see parent and vendor folder. Inside the vendor folder, I do not see auto, setup, or index (ie what to run).

Looking at 2) ie Magento with sample data. I navigated with local host and got 2 messages.

Error Messages I see: "

> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp\www\MagentoD\vendor/magento/module-theme/registration.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\MagentoD\vendor\composer\autoload_real .php on line 60"

and

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp\www\MagentoD\vendor/magento/module-theme/registration.php'
>   (include_path='C:\wamp\www\MagentoD\vendor/magento/zendframework1/library;C:\wamp\www\MagentoD\vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator;C:\wamp\www\MagentoD\vendor/phpunit/phpunit;C:\wamp\www\MagentoD\vendor/symfony/yaml;.;C:\php\pear')
>   in C:\wamp\www\MagentoD\vendor\composer\autoload_real .php on line 60"

In my research on how to install Magento 2, there was a mention of setup wizard and unluckily, I have not seen it in the downloaded (method 2 dwnld). Appreciate any help in getting this thing to run and ideally with sample data. Currently tired and hoping for help in your forum. tx

****** Addition- Sept 24 *****

Did not know I have a 5 minute time limit to do edit. Thus, this insertion on  my train of thought. Comment limit thus addition done here. thanks

I have never worked with Magento and Composer and thus I will make rookie mistakes. Assistance appreciated to avoided first timer mistakes. With my problem installing Magento 2, I decided to troubleshoot if my installation satisfy the mandatory and list my installation checklist.

**Downloaded:**

```
Magento-CE-2.0.9-2016-08-10-03-31-28.tar.bz2
Magento-CE-2.1.1_sample_data-2016-08-29-06-53-55.tar.bx2
wampserver3.0.4_x86_apache2.4.18_mysql5.7.11_php5.6.19-7.0.4
composer ver 4.5
```

Magento key 
Above will then be the environment of what I am using.

**Pre-checklist:**

- Enabled `mod_rewrite module` in Apache (how do I check if mod_rewrite is enabled? If it is disabled, how to I enable it on Apache?). In Apache, I look at apache module and I see mod_rewrite has a green arrow check mark.
- "`Composer -help`" or list to make sure composer is install. It is install when I did/check in cmd with help option.
  In an article, it is mention to make sure composer is install globally (Will look into that - how to determine if global and how to make it global?)
- In  `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19\php.ini`, I see the following are commented out below ( ie install).
- In  `C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.4\php.ini`, I did not check for it says not to edit that file in comment when I open/access.
- In  `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache 2.4.18\php.ini`, I cannot access (I cannot open like I did in C).

**Enable list of extension in php.ini (C - commented out):**

```
php_pdo_mysql
php_mbstring
php_xmlrpc
php_curl
php_xsl
php_soap
php_intl
php_openssl
```

Window setup wizard install for Magento - Will try to find html article and try.

Have a feeling I am not using Composer properly to install Magento, and there is something interesting in a stack forum. Will investigate.

In `Magento-CE-2.0.9-2016-08-10-03-31-28`, I unzip and put into www. To document my adventure more fully.

`Magento-CE-2.1.1_sample_data-2016-08-29-06-53-55.tar`, I unzip and put into www with different name. To document my adventure more fully.

To document my adventure or keep trying with different platform.(easy dev or AMP or who knows to get this install done. I am under the weather and it is does not help researching how to).

When documenting, write for a newbie and life will be easy for all. I hope my encounter will help newbies and how to writers. I have not played with a PHP package over the years - CMS or Event app and might involve curl, pear or soap. It such a long time and Mag would have been easy to install if life is a bed of roses.

Comment: An quote I recently got from a sideline magento developer states in an very opinionated manner: "Magento developers should not take into consideration improper local environments for development. 
Hope we'll get a proper check in bootstrap soon which would prevent installation under Windows just like it is prevented for older PHP versions."

Comment: Rando developers like the above are consistently making contributions to magento core that breaks everything for wamp

Comment: See commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8110949e4dd4faa8d36b25ecfeb7779ebbac5741

Answer (score 0):

> 1. For your first method:

- About using PHP command with Wamp or Xampp on Windows, you must register php.exe as an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE so the command line can recognize the 'php' command instead of needing to enter the full path ( in my test case: `E:\Wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10;` ) as the command.
- About using Composer command on Windows, you just download and run [Composer-Setup.exe](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe). It will install the latest Composer version and set up your PATH so that you can just call composer from any directory in your command line.
- After that, you should run: `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation directory name>` in Command Prompt and do next steps in [this document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#integrator-first-composer-ce).

> 2. For your second method:

- Before you run the web setup wizard, you should change the permission of your installation directory.
- Just right click on your directory then go **Properties** > **Security** > choose **Users** then click **Edit** and *choose **Users** again* then check **Full Control** and click OK to grant permission.
- Finally, you can continue installing your Magento.

> **P/S**:

In my opinion, you should try Ubuntu or MacOS for learning Magento because it's easy to setup and run the commands. Actually I am using Windows and setup Magento on Ubuntu built in Windows 10...

Comment: Appreciate your reply David since I am under the weather. In step 1, point number 3, will attempt in the future. Lol, in step 2 (second method), will have to find the html documentation reference to setup wizard. Also, step 2, will keep in mind of full control permission. Tx

Answer (score 0):

> I've also tried installing magento 2.3 using WAMP and found several
> similar issues.

After spending some hours patching things up, and some research, I've come across the following conclusions:

## Why not to install magento in Windows

- A select few, sideline, unapologetic magento developers have trickled in commits that break everything
- The official stance is that magento will no longer accept patches to fix stuff in windows, even though code has been introduced before that did.
- There are several closed issues on github pertaining to the windows environment
- Composer updates will overwrite any patches made to fix windows breaking code
- Expect a check to fail in setup for windows environment in the future
- Expect the amount of windows developers / compatible answers to dwindle, some useful help topics may only contain answers for Ubuntu install environments

> links:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8110949e4dd4faa8d36b25ecfeb7779ebbac5741
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19471#issuecomment-443195351